# Jersey/JAX-RS : How to cascade beans-validation recursively with @Valid automatically?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I am validating my POJOs in a REST resource endpoint in Jersey:

```
public class Resource {
    @POST
    public Response post(@NotNull @Valid final POJO pojo) {
        ...
    }
}

public class POJO {
    @NotNull
    protected final String name;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected final POJOInner inner;

    ...
}

public class POJOInner {
    @Min(0)
    protected final int limit;

    ...
}
```

This seems to work fine.

However, the `@Min(0)` annotation is only verified if the field `inner` has the `@Valid` annotation. It doesn't feel right to add the `@Valid` annotation to each field which isn't a primitive.

Is there a way to tell the bean validator to automatically recursively continue the validation, even when no `@Valid` annotation is present? I would like my `POJO` to be as following:

```
public class POJO {
    @NotNull
    protected final String name;

    @NotNull
    protected final POJOInner inner;

    ...
}
```

Comment: What bean validation runtime are you using?

Comment: I am using the Hibernate Validator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, according to the specification, adding @Valid is exactly for this usecase. From the JSR 303 specification:

> In addition to supporting instance validation, validation of graphs of object is also supported. The result of a graph validation is returned as a unified set of constraint violations.
>   Consider the situation where bean X contains a field of type Y. By annotating field Y with the @Valid annotation, the Validator will validate Y (and its properties) when X is validated.
>
> ...
>
> The @Valid annotation is applied recursively

Comment: Spring does not do this by default.. i'm using spring boot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: While this might be true it does not explain if it is possible to achieve recursive validation without needing to annotate all members, which is what OP is asking..

Comment: What resolves this IMO is obtaining a custom validator and adding a TraversableResolve as in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#example-traversable-resolver

This would be better than cluttering the codebase with `@Valid` annotations if the intent it to validate the whole object graph.

Comment: "The @Valid annotation is applied recursively" it does not seem to in hibernate implementation though...

Comment: [JSR 303](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/bean_validation-1_0-final-spec.pdf)